# Criar trigger entre tabelas

Tags: java, mysql, query, trigger

Estou fazendo um trabalho aqui e me deparei com um problema, nosso sistema é um sistema de automação residencial utilizando `java` e `mysql`.

Criamos duas tabelas para `logs` sendo que a primeira guarda o dispositivo, usuário e o data exata que foi ligado ou desligado e a segunda teoricamente guarda o tempo que tal dispositivo ficou ligado.

**tb_log**

```
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |    
| dispositivo | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |    
| usuario     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |    
| data        | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |    
| status      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

**tb_log_per**

```
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
| id          | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dispositivo | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| usuario     | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| periodo     | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

A ideia principal era criar uma `trigger` para que cada vez que for inserido no banco um `log` de dispositivo com a operação desativar, automaticamente a `trigger` deveria inserir no `log` de período as informações junto do período de tempo. Porém, para isso eu tive de colocar um `SELECT` para encontrar a última data de ativação do dispositivo e com isso recebo erro de sintaxe no `SELECT` não importa como eu faça.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_log_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON tb_log 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF( NEW.status = 'Desativado') 
THEN INSERT INTO tb_log_per (dispositivo,usuario,periodo) 
     VALUES (NEW.dispositivo,NEW.usuario,
             TIMEDIFF(SELECT data FROM tb_log WHERE dispositivo = 1 
             AND status = 'Ativo' ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1),NEW.data);
```

Alguem sabe como eu posso realizar essa operação?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! Recomendo que faça um [tour] pelo nosso site e veja [ask].

Comment: Não existe ORDER BY em select.

Comment: Como assim não existe `ORDER BY` em `SELECT` @Motta? Na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) diz isso onde?

Comment: Leia-se em INSERT , perdão.

Comment: @Motta o `ORDER BY` ele esta usando no `SELECT` dentro do `INSERT`, não tem erro nenhum nisso.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente ocorre o erro de `sintaxe` porque esta faltando abrir um `(` antes do `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_log_insert AFTER INSERT ON tb_log FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF( NEW.status = 'Desativado') THEN
            INSERT INTO tb_log_per (dispositivo, usuario, periodo) VALUES (NEW.dispositivo, NEW.usuario, TIMEDIFF((
                SELECT data FROM tb_log
                WHERE dispositivo = 1 AND status = 'Ativo'
                ORDER BY data DESC
                LIMIT 1),
            NEW.data);
```